# Can't SSH into Ubuntu Desktop from Windows laptop via ethernet cable

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ethernet

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 LTE Desktop and a Windows 10 laptop. I would like to SSH from windows 10 via Cygwin (or whatever else is convenient) into the Desktop but would prefer to use an ethernet cable for direct connection between the two, as opposed to wifi. Using SSH to the wireless local IP address works fine but I cannot get it to work via ethernet.

Here is the info for my Ubuntu Desktop

```
$ ifconfig -a
enp69s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6961:bda5:85a6:4150  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a8:a1:59:18:6c:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 86049  bytes 7681993 (7.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 215  bytes 27497 (27.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xb7600000-b761ffff  

enp71s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a8:a1:59:18:6c:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

gpd0: flags=4240<POINTOPOINT,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4129  bytes 488109 (488.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4129  bytes 488109 (488.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp70s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.57  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 2601:2c5:c780:e3f0:142a:9cd:ee13:3f75  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2601:2c5:c780:e3f0:817e:ff1:3daf:22e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::af6e:ce97:8156:93db  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2601:2c5:c780:e3f0::8abc  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 24:41:8c:95:cc:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 167161  bytes 75026317 (75.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78430  bytes 18079733 (18.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`enp69s0` is the ethernet cable connecting to my laptop. In my Cygwin terminal, connecting through the wireless router works fine:

```
ssh username@10.0.0.57
```

But when I attempt to ssh to the address `192.168.1.1` it does not. In fact, when I type `ping 192.168.1.1` it would say Connection timed out. I would prefer to use a direct connection, so any help or advice would be helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: Problem fixed after changing the IP address of enp69s0 from 192.168.1.1 to another value 192.168.1.3. Didn't realize that 192.168.1.1 is usually reserved for the router.

EDIT2: Added my own answer

Comment: Are the two computers directly connected to each other by Ethernet cable, or are they connected via a router or a switch? What is the Ethernet IP address of the Windows computer. The 192.168.1.1 is usually reserved for the router.

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question and show us `ip route`. Can you `ping -I enp69s0 192.168.1.1`?

Comment: Hi guys, the problem indeed was having my ubuntu IP address set as 192.168.1.1. Changing it to 192.168.1.3 fixed my problem (my windows IP address was 192.168.1.2)

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer. Or I can convert my comment to an answer. In either case you should accept the answer as correct with the green  check mark ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed after changing the IP address of `enp69s0` from `192.168.1.1` to another value `192.168.1.3`. Didn't realize that `192.168.1.1` is usually reserved for the router.